# How to change legendary ring characteristics?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is it possible to change secondary characteristics of legendary ring from the legendary quest chain?

They are good, but not ideal (one of them is the most important for my spec, but another is the less important). One put a lot of effort into upgrading this ring, it would be a pity to waste it afterwards because of characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reforge your ring to change a particular characteristic.

You can however speak to [Zouti Fizzlefury](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=86949/zooti-fizzlefury) at **Zagarra** to buy the other ring available to your class which will have two preset different secondary characteristic, which might be more to your liking or simply be a better choice for your second spec.

- Intellect ring:  **Versatility & Mastery** or **Haste & Spirit**
- Strength ring: **Critical Strike & Multistrike** or **Versatility & Bonus Armor**
- Agility ring: **Critical Strike & Versatility** or **Versatility & Bonus Armor**

Typically the first one is for dps and the second one for heal or tank.

Note that the second ring won't be upgraded during the legendary quest line, so you'll have to rebuy it at each step if you don't want to wait the final step to buy it.

- ilvl 640: 500po
- ilvl 680: 1000po
- ilvl 690: 1500po
- ilvl 715: 2000po

Comment: Thank you. I have more questions: Can you chose both secodary characteristics when buying? Or you get random secondary characteristics? And most important: Can you upgrade bought ring using quests? In this case you better buy the optimal ring when it is still 640, right?

Comment: wrong info is wrong. The rings are designed for diffrent roles. All int dps get the same ring, all agi dps get the same ring etc. They also share the same proc, so you cant change the 2nd stats by going to the vendor. He just sells 5 diffrent rings for 5 diffrent class/role combos

Comment: @klm123 No the ring's characteristic are preset. For example, the Intellect ring has either Haste & Spirit or Versatility & Mastery. The alt ring unfortunately don't upgrade with the main ring during the quest; so you'll have to buy the alt spec ring at the final stage or rebuy one at each step, depending on your need.

Comment: @rwank That's what I meant to say but you're right of pointing it out, I edited for clarity.

Comment: Em. I went to this NPC and see exactly the same ring, which I have and NO other options. Basing on what you say that "which will have two preset different secondary characteristic, which might be more to your liking "?

Comment: @klm123 You might need to set that you want the ring for another spec. For example if you're Priest, ask to see all of the equipments instead of just Shadow spec's ones.

Comment: I see. Ok. Last question, you are saying that this quest (if you start it with new character) will never give you Mastery&Haste, for example? All characteristics are preset and depends on your speciality, no random is involved in the quest reward? Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I accept it.

Comment: @klm123 Yes, the rings have the same preset for everyone and unfortunately I don't believe Blizzard have made plans to change that for the ilvl 735 ring. So some class and spec are more advantaged than others if the two characteristics of the ring are the best for their spec.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the stats on the legendary ring, since blizzard removed reforging with the release of WoD